# How to create basic Google glass app in Android and IOS

Tags: android, ios5, google-glass

I would to like to create my glass(Hello world) application for google glass both in Android & IOS can any one help me in how to create basic application.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a Hello World for glass, not for Android or iOS.

You can begin to read the GDK Quick Start (https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/quick-start).

You have examples here -> https://developers.google.com/glass/samples/gdk

Comment: Thanks for your support can you say how can we create glass apps on xcode thanks in advance

Comment: @AdityaHariKishan Step 1, from the guide Bae linked: "Get the Android 4.4.2 (API 19) SDK and Glass Development Kit Preview add-on from the Android SDK Manager". *Use Android Studio or Eclipse.*